# Windows 10 doesn't change start menu color automatically - is it a bug?

Tags: windows-10

I have a problem with Windows 10:

[image]

System language is Polish, but I checked all 3 options that are responsible for changing Start menu color automatically and as you can see, majority of background is green. Here's my question - **why Windows 10 doesn't change menu color automatically?**

I know it worked at first, then I changed something and it stopped working. Since then I reinstalled W10 2 times and it still doesn't work.

I'd like to see some help, because for me, it looks like a bug and at the same time, it worked at the beginning :/

Do you have any ideas why does it happen?

Comment: I don't see any green in your screnshot except for the green in the desktop background.

Comment: That's what I meant - a wallpaper. That's where the color should be picked up from, isn't it?

Comment: I still don't understand.  It isn't going to pick green, its going to pick an accent color.

Comment: Yes, it does, but do you see what color is now?

Comment: So if you change the wallpaper now, the colouring stays the same?

Comment: yes :/ however, when I created new user, it worked...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and fixed it using this method:

1. Go to control panel
2. Go to Ease of Access
3. Choose optimize visual display
4. Select "make things on the screen easier to see "
5. Under this sentence there are three check boxes, check box the second box:

   ```
    • turn off all unnecessary animation
   ```

This works for me after a restart. It seems that the animation makes lag or something like that.